# linux-headers-3.14-kali1-amd64 --- Download + manual install

Tags: linux, packages

I need the linux-headers package above to install my Wifi card drivers. As I own a MacAir I cannot connect to the web without wifi drivers.
How do I install the linux header package manually? As I have a dual boot system I can connect to wireless and download stuff via OSX, but I did not find any help on this matter yet.
I would guess that I need to find the .deb package of the linux headers somewhere and then run dpkg -i on the file in the linux boot?

EDIT:
It seems like manual package install is a pain because of all the dependencies. Any other ideas?

Comment: http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/ think I found it here... will try now

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: You shouldn't try installing another distribution's package on another distro

Comment: These questions wwould be better answered on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: using kali-linux-1.0.7-amd64

Comment: If you have another kali linux machine, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756800/how-to-download-all-dependencies-and-packages-to-directory) would work

Comment: The linux-headers package was probably on you install media

Answer (score -1):

If you have Synaptic on your machine, you can use [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Installing_packages_without_an_Internet_connection) to  generate a list of the debs you need to install.

The script may run on OSX - it would probably use wget or curl.
If not you should be able to inspect the script and download those packages.

## UPDATE

[An apt-get only solution](http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/517)

```
apt-get --print-uris --yes install pkgspec | grep ^\' | cut -d\' -f2 >downloads.list
```

Comment: i tried `apt-get --print-uris --yes install linux-headers-$(uname -r) | grep ^\' | cut -d\' -f2 >downloads.list` but I received the error: `E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).` and the downloads.list file gets created but stays blank

Comment: Try it again with no packages specified, download those files, and then try again.

Comment: as before. download.list gets created but stays blank. But no errors.

Comment: Have you forced install of any package?

Comment: what do you mean by that? I tried to use -f on the header package but nothing happened either.

Comment: Hmm are you sure? Try removing it?

Comment: Do you mean I should try to dpkg -f some package I have around?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look to the [docs](http://docs.kali.org/) and see [this link](http://docs.kali.org/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-wireless-driver-issues) for WiFi driver problems:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Try providing more details about your MacBook Air, especially the Wi-Fi AirPort card.

Answer (score -1):

First, find out all the dependencies of this package, for example, [this way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80655/how-can-i-check-dependency-list-for-a-deb-package).

Then, proceed to download all of the `deb` packages that are not part of the base Kali system.

Finally, copy them to your system (for example, with the help of an USB Flash Drive) and install them with

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: We have a troll in this thread who voted down the question and every answer. If you're an admin and can see this, please report them.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you do this:

```
apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

Before:

```
apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```